# What is the fastest way to generate the n-th Motzkin number?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, motzkin-numbers

I want to generate all the [Motzkin Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number) and store in an array. The formula is given as follows:
[image]

My current implementation is just way too slow:

```
void generate_slow() {
    mm[0] = 1;
    mm[1] = 1;
    mm[2] = 2;
    mm[3] = 4;
    mm[4] = 9;
    ull result;
    for (int i = 5; i <= MAX_NUMBERS; ++i) {
        result = mm[i - 1];
        for (int k = 0; k <= (i - 2); ++k) {
            result = (result + ((mm[k] * mm[i - 2 - k]) % MODULO)) % MODULO;
        }
        mm[i] = result;
    }
}

void generate_slightly_faster() {
    mm[0] = 1;
    mm[1] = 1;
    mm[2] = 2;
    mm[3] = 4;
    mm[4] = 9;
    ull result;
    for (int i = 5; i <= MAX_NUMBERS; ++i) {
        result = mm[i - 1];
        for (int l = 0, r = i - 2; l <= r; ++l, --r) {
            if (l != r) {
                result = (result + (2 * (mm[l] * mm[r]) % MODULO)) % MODULO;
            }
            else {
                result = (result + ((mm[l] * mm[r]) % MODULO)) % MODULO;
            }
        }
        mm[i] = result;
    }
}
```

Besides, I'm stuck with finding a closed form for the recurrence matrix so that I can apply exponentiation squaring. Can anyone suggest a better algorithm? Thanks.
**Edit** I can't apply the second formula because division doesn't apply when modulo a number. The maximum of `n` is 10,000 which is beyond the range of 64-bit integer, so the answer is modulo with a larger number `m` where `m` = 10^14 + 7. Larger integer library is not allowed.

Comment: You might want to make your title a bit more interesting ;)

Comment: I don't get it. Have you implemented the expression for M_{n+1} which only depends on n,M_n and M_{n-1}? That should be fast.

Comment: @Jacob: Sorry for not to mention. Yes, I implemented that method but the division part doesn't apply for modular arithmetic.

Comment: Could you explain the need for modular arithmetic? It's not clear from your recurrence relation for M_{n+1}

Comment: @Jacob: The problem is asking for the 10,000th Motzkin number which obviously beyond the range of 64-bit number, so they ask for the answer mod with a number `m`. Furthermore, it's not possible to use large integer library.

Comment: why not http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @user827992: Already asked, but I guess this problem is more relevant to programming technique. The mathematics formula is trivial as you can see from the second formula.

Comment: You say "the problem" - is this homework or an interview question, or some programming challenge?

Comment: @therefromhere: Yes it is a programming challenge.

Comment: just curious, but where is this problem from?

Comment: @Felix: It's from Codechef, but the original problem have other parts as well. This problem is only part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can use the second formula. The division can be done with the [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). Even if the modular number is not prime, which makes it difficult, it is also possible (I found some helpful hints in the [discussion](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/1968/maxgame-editorial) to the [MAXGAME challenge](http://www.codechef.com/AUG12/problems/MAXGAME)):

> Prime factorise MOD as = 43 * 1103 * 2083 * 1012201. Compute all quantities modulo each of these primes and then use chinese remainder theorem to find out the value modulo MOD. Beware, as here divison is also involved, for each quantity one would need to maintain the highest powers of each of these primes which divides them as well.

Following C++ program prints the first 10000 Motzkin numbers modulo 100000000000007:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

// Exctended Euclidean algorithm: Takes a, b as input, and return a
// triple (g, x, y), such that ax + by = g = gcd(a, b)
// (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/
// Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)
void egcd(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t& g, int64_t& x, int64_t& y) {
    if (!a) {
        g = b; x = 0; y = 1;
        return;
    }
    int64_t gtmp, xtmp, ytmp;
    egcd(b % a, a, gtmp, ytmp, xtmp);
    g = gtmp; x = xtmp - (b / a) * ytmp; y = ytmp;
}

// Modular Multiplicative Inverse
bool modinv(int64_t a, int64_t mod, int64_t& ainv) {
    int64_t g, x, y;
    egcd(a, mod, g, x, y);
    if (g != 1)
        return false;
    ainv = x % mod;
    if (ainv < 0)
        ainv += mod;
    return true;
}

// returns (a * b) % mod
// uses Russian Peasant multiplication
// (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12171020/237483)
int64_t mulmod(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t mod) {
    if (a < 0) a += mod;
    if (b < 0) b += mod;
    int64_t res = 0;
    while (a != 0) {
        if (a & 1) res = (res + b) % mod;
        a >>= 1;
        b = (b << 1) % mod;
    }
    return res;
}

// Takes M_n-2 (m0) and M_n-1 (m1) and returns n-th Motzkin number
// all numbers are modulo mod
int64_t motzkin(int64_t m0, int64_t m1, int n, int64_t mod) {
    int64_t tmp1 = ((2 * n + 3) * m1 + (3 * n * m0));
    int64_t tmp2 = n + 3;

    // return 0 if mod divides tmp1 because:
    // 1. mod is prime
    // 2. if gcd(tmp2, mod) != 1 --> no multiplicative inverse!
    // --> 3. tmp2 is a multiple from mod
    // 4. tmp2 divides tmp1 (Motzkin numbers aren't floating point numbers)
    // --> 5. mod divides tmp1
    // --> tmp1 % mod = 0
    // --> (tmp1 * tmp2^(-1)) % mod = 0
    if (!(tmp1 % mod))
        return 0;

    int64_t tmp3;
    if (!modinv(tmp2, mod, tmp3))
        throw std::runtime_error("No multiplicative inverse");
    return (tmp1 * tmp3) % mod;
}

int main() {
    const int64_t M    = 100000000000007;
    const int64_t MD[] = { 43, 1103, 2083, 1012201 }; // Primefactors
    const int64_t MX[] = { M/MD[0], M/MD[1], M/MD[2], M/MD[3] };
    int64_t e1[4];

    // Precalculate e1 for the Chinese remainder algo
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int64_t g, x, y;
        egcd(MD[i], MX[i], g, x, y);
        e1[i] = MX[i] * y;
        if (e1[i] < 0)
            e1[i] += M;
    }

    int64_t m0[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    int64_t m1[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    for (int n = 1; n < 10000; n++) {

        // Motzkin number for each factor
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int64_t tmp = motzkin(m0[i], m1[i], n, MD[i]);
            m0[i] = m1[i];
            m1[i] = tmp;
        }

        // Chinese remainder theorem
        int64_t res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            res += mulmod(m1[i], e1[i], M);
            res %= M;
        }
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether it happens for the primes considered, but the reasoning for "return 0 if mod divides tmp1 because: ... (tmp1 * tmp2^(-1)) % mod = 0" is wrong. For example, M_9 = 835 is not divisible by 11, the calculation is `M_9 = (19*323 + 24*127)/11 = (5*11*167)/11 = 5*167`.

Comment: It bites here too. M_84 is not divisible by 43, the factorisation of `(2*83*M_83 + 3*83*M_82)` is `[(2,1),(5,1),(19,1),(43,1),(15887,1),(42020639,1),(349259661165016424944007,1)]`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I am afraid you are right, my reasoning was wrong. I will try to correct the function. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: THE FOLLOWING CODE IS WRONG BECAUSE IT USES INTEGER DIVISION (e.g. 5/2 = 2 not 2.5). Feel free to fix it!

This is a good chance to use dynamic programming. It is very similar for working out Fibonacci numbers.

```
sample code:

cache = {}
cache[0] = 1
cache[1] = 1

def motzkin(n):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    else:
        result = 3*n*motzkin(n - 2)/(n + 3) + (2*n + 3)*motzkin(n - 1)/(n + 3)
        cache[n] = result
        return result

for i in range(10):
    print i, motzkin(i)

print motzkin(1000)

"""
0 1
1 1
2 2
3 4
4 9
5 21
6 53
7 134
8 346
9 906
75794754010998216916857635442484411813743978100571902845098110153309261636322340168650370511949389501344124924484495394937913240955817164730133355584393471371445661970273727286877336588424618403572614523888534965515707096904677209192772199599003176027572021460794460755760991100028703368873821893050902166740481987827822643139384161298315488092901472934255559058881743019252022468893544043541453423967661847226330177828070589283132360685783010085347614855435535263090005810
"""
```

The problem is because these numbers get so big, storing them all in the cache will run out of memeory if you want to go really high. Then it is better to use a for loop remembering the previous 2 terms. If you want to find the motzkin number for many numbers, I suggest you sort your numbers first, and then as you approach each of your numbers in the for loop, output the result.

EDIT: I created a looped version but got different results to my previous recursive function. At least one of them must be wrong!! Hopefully you still see how it works and can fix it!

```
def motzkin2(numbers):
    numbers.sort() #assumes no duplicates
    up_to = 0
    if numbers[0] == 0:
        yield 1
        up_to += 1
    if 1 in numbers[:2]:
        yield 1
        up_to += 1

    max_ = numbers[-1]
    m0 = 1
    m1 = 1
    for n in range(3, max_ + 1):
        m2 = 3*n*m0/(n + 3) + (2*n + 3)*m1/(n + 3)
        if n == numbers[up_to]:
            yield n, m2
            up_to += 1
        m0, m1 = m1, m2



for pair in motzkin2([9,1,3,7, 1000]):
    print pair

"""
1
(3, 2)
(7, 57)
(9, 387)
(1000, 32369017020536373226194869003219167142048874154652342993932240158930603189131202414912032918968097703139535871364048699365879645336396657663119183721377260183677704306107525149452521761041198342393710275721776790421499235867633215952014201548763282500175566539955302783908853370899176492629575848442244003609595110883079129592139070998456707801580368040581283599846781393163004323074215163246295343379138928050636671035367010921338262011084674447731713736715411737862658025L)
"""
```

Comment: Is this code useful to anyone or should I delete it? Seeing as i forgot about modular division :X. You could use Euclids algorithm to work out the inverse in that mod to fix it :X