# Compute (a*b)%n FAST for 64-bit unsigned arguments in C(++) on x86-64 platforms?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, x86-64, 128-bit

I'm looking for a **fast** method to efficiently compute   (`a`⋅`b`) modulo `n`  (in the mathematical sense of that) for `a`, `b`, `n` of type `uint64_t`. I could live with preconditions such as `n!=0`, or even `a<n && b<n`.

Notice that the C expression `(a*b)%n` won't cut it, because the product is truncated to 64 bits. I'm looking for `(uint64_t)(((uint128_t)a*b)%n)` except that I do not have a `uint128_t` (that I know, in Visual C++).

I'm in for a Visual C++ (preferably) or GCC/clang intrinsic making best use of the underlying hardware available on x86-64 platforms; or if that can't be done for a portable `inline` function.

Comment: Use a big-number library? It might even have fast modulo.

Comment: @self: This does not lead to a fast solution, I'm afraid. I know GMP, and love it for a quickly done program under MinGW32. But when performance really counts and small arguments, it may not be fast enough for my taste. I admit I did not check.

Comment: @self. These libraries are virtually always optimized for very large numbers (and sometimes smaller-than-word-sized integers too). Their algorithms, however, can probably be re purposed for this special case with some loop unrolling and manual register allocation.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168348/ways-to-do-modulo-multiplication-with-primitive-types

Comment: @Nikolay: looks very much like the second example [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12168589/903600) does exactly what I want!

Comment: @fgrieu: note that the example you linked to uses inline assembler which MSVC doesn't support for 64-bit targets. However, it should be easy enough to make it a stand-alone assembler function that's linked in.  Or you could compile that one C function with inline assembler using MinGW and link that object file in to your MSVC projecgt.

Comment: Is there a reason why `((a%n)*(b%n))%n` won't do?

Comment: @Guido: `((a%n)*(b%n))%n` won't do when `n` is large. Example: `a=b=0x123456789` and `n=0x234567891`. `a%n` and `b%n` are `0x123456789`. `(a%n)*(b%n)` is `0x4b66dc326fb98751`, truncated from `0x14b66dc326fb98751`. `((a%n)*(b%n))%n` is `0x11b3c4d59`, instead of the mathematically correct `0x141cebed5`.

Comment: It's easy to do multi-precision multiply/add/subtract.  Hard to do multi-precision divide.  There are a few tricks, but they don't help much.  In fact, it's sometimes fastest to do successive approximation, if the multiply is fast enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most accurate way to do a combined multiply-and-divide operation in 64-bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733178/most-accurate-way-to-do-a-combined-multiply-and-divide-operation-in-64-bit)

Comment: @Peter Cordes; sorry, that was a silly move in the the joy of the instant, thanks for fixing my eclipse of the mind. [I'll remove that comment within 24h].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7 years later, I got a solution working in Visual Studio 2019

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#pragma intrinsic(_umul128)
#pragma intrinsic(_udiv128)

// compute (a*b)%n with 128-bit intermediary result
// assumes n>0  and  a*b < n * 2**64 (always the case when a<=n || b<=n )
inline uint64_t mulmod(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t n) {
  uint64_t r, s = _umul128(a, b, &r);
  (void)_udiv128(r, s, n, &r);
  return r;
}

// compute (a*b)%n with 128-bit intermediary result
// assumes n>0, works including if a*b >= n * 2**64
inline uint64_t mulmod1(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t n) {
  uint64_t r, s = _umul128(a % n, b, &r);
  (void)_udiv128(r, s, n, &r);
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, how about this (not tested)

```
modmul:
; rcx = a
; rdx = b
; r8 = n
mov rax, rdx
mul rcx
div r8
mov rax, rdx
ret
```

The precondition is that `a * b / n <= ~0ULL`, otherwise there will be a divide error. That's a slightly less strict condition than `a < n && m < n`, one of them can be bigger than `n` as long as the other is small enough.

Unfortunately it has to be assembled and linked in separately, because MSVC doesn't support inline asm for 64bit targets.

It's also still slow, the real problem is that 64bit `div`, which can take nearly a hundred cycles (seriously, up to 90 cycles on Nehalem for example).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `div` has a 128-bit dividend, not 64-bit as your answer appears to indicate.

Comment: It might also be worth it using inline assembler so that compiler may inline this trivial code and save on function call overhead.

Comment: @vlad the visual c++ x86_64 compiler doesn't support inline assembly, as the answer notes.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Then I am glad I don't have to use it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it the old-fashioned way with shift/add/subtract.  The below code assumes `a` < `n` and
 `n` < 2<sup>63</sup> (so things don't overflow):

```
uint64_t mulmod(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t n) {
    uint64_t rv = 0;
    while (b) {
        if (b&1)
            if ((rv += a) >= n) rv -= n;
        if ((a += a) >= n) a -= n;
        b >>= 1; }
    return rv;
}
```

You could use `while (a && b)` for the loop instead to short-circuit things if it's likely that `a` will be a factor of `n`.  Will be slightly slower (more comparisons and likely correctly predicted branches) if `a` is not a factor of `n`.

If you really, absolutely, need that last bit (allowing `n` up to 2<sup>64</sup>-1), you can use:

```
uint64_t mulmod(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t n) {
    uint64_t rv = 0;
    while (b) {
        if (b&1) {
            rv += a;
            if (rv < a || rv >= n) rv -= n; }
        uint64_t t = a;
        a += a;
        if (a < t || a >= n) a -= n;
        b >>= 1; }
    return rv;
}
```

Alternately, just use GCC instrinsics to access the underlying x64 instructions:

```
inline uint64_t mulmod(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t n) {
    uint64_t rv;
    asm ("mul %3" : "=d"(rv), "=a"(a) : "1"(a), "r"(b));
    asm ("div %4" : "=d"(rv), "=a"(a) : "0"(rv), "1"(a), "r"(n));
    return rv;
}
```

The 64-bit div instruction is *really* slow, however, so the loop might actually be faster.  You'd need to profile to be sure.

Comment: You've got overflow problems (they don't create undefined behavior for integral types, but they will mess up the comparison).  You need to use the technique shown in my answer to circumvent that (and yes, I realized that the multiplication can be done in my same loop).

Comment: True, but fgrieu emphasized in the comments that the case when n >= 2**63 is the one of most concern.

Comment: @BenVoigt: ok, if you absolutely need that last bit, you can manually check for overflow, making the code just a little bit slower.

Comment: Could not `a += a;` mathematically overflow is `a >= 2**63`? or is that compensated by the `if (a < t` part?

Comment: @chux: exactly -- overflow will wrap with unsigned numbers, so `a < t` implies that `a += a` overflowed, and the actual value for the sum is `a + 2**64`, but that is less than `2*n`, so after subtracting `n` we'll underflow (reversing the effect of the overflow) and be back in the valid range of a uint64_t.

Comment: Thanks.  Idea: If one wanted to avoid overflow (maybe because using `int`), code could instead use `type_of_n nhalf = n/2; /* one time calculation */ .....  if (a >= nhalf) a -= n-a; else a += a;`.

Comment: if you use a signed type, you lose a bit to the sign, as well as losing predictable overflow behaviour.  You still need an extra (hard to predict) branch to avoid the overflow, so it doesn't save you anything.

Answer (score 1):

This intrinsic is named [`__mul128`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82cxdw50%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
typedef unsigned long long BIG;

// handles only the "hard" case when high bit of n is set
BIG shl_mod( BIG v, BIG n, int by )
{
    if (v > n) v -= n;
    while (by--) {
        if (v > (n-v))
            v -= n-v;
        else
            v <<= 1;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Now you can use `shl_mod(B, n, 64)`

Comment: But unfortunately, this performs only the product.

Comment: That catches me every time... most MSDN links the version can be removed to make a link to latest, for this it can't.  Now fixed.

Comment: @fgrieu: Correct, but the complaint in your question was about truncation of the product.  This avoids that.  Now you need to perform `(A * (2**64) + B) % n` (where `A` and `B` are the results of the multiply, not your original `a` and `b`), which simplifies to `((A % n) * (2**64 % n)) % n + B % n`... and there are well-known methods for this.  Do you use the same `n` repeatedly?  In that case, precompute `2**64 % n`

Comment: When both high and low bits of `n` are set, I know no fast method for `(A * (2**64) + B) % n`

Comment: Did not get your hint. When both high and low bits of `n` are set, `2**64 % n`is `0U-n`, and `2**32 % n` `is 1ULL<<32`. Neither helps so much. Ah, or perhaps you suggest to pre-compute `2**128 / n` and do [Barrett reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_reduction)? That's a tad complex.

Comment: Right, the 2**32 was useless.  I was going to suggest the `-n`, but I see you've already got that.

Comment: @fgrieu: Can you see anything wrong with the function I just added to my answer?

Comment: It looks to me that the code you posted correctly computes `(2**64 * v)%n` when the high bit of `n` is set, which indeed is the hardest case in the computation of `(A * (2**64) + B) % n`, in which we want to compute `shl_mod(A, n, 64)`. My only issue is with the execution time. That extends to other `n`, e.g. with the but-highest bit set.

Comment: It would be interesting to see optimized code generated for that by your favorite compiler.  I think that `v > (n-v)` will be done by actually calculating `v - (n-v)` and checking the overflow bit... therefore not recalculating the difference on the next line.  If the loop is unrolled, there could be only about 4 instructions per iteration, and these are all low strength operations, likely to retire several per cycle, so it could be only a few percent slower than the DIV instruction used by Harold's assembly solution.

Comment: [Clang-3.8 -O3 makes near-ideal code](https://godbolt.org/g/D1t3tp) (which as you suggest, branches on the result of a `sub`.)  The serial dependencies limit loop throughput to one iteration per 5 clocks (on Intel Haswell), according to IACA.  I only see 4 cycles of latency (since neither `mov` is on the critical path, but IACA thinks `mov rdx, rdi` is) , but even so, 4c * 64 is *far* worse than a `div r64` (32-96 cycles latency on Haswell, similar on Skylake.  We should probably expect the time to be towards the upper end of that range if the quotient has most of its bits set.)

Comment: So if you're confident the `div` won't fault (e.g. quotient overflows a 64bit reg), hardware `div` is a much better bet.  BTW, Broadwell/Skylake have 1c latency on `cmov`, but even 3c * 64 is not a win.

Comment: If you can interleave maybe four of these calculations in the same loop, then you can certainly come out ahead, because multiple dependency chains in parallel creates instruction-level parallelism.  The out-of-order execution window isn't big enough to start working on a 2nd loop before the first loop is mostly done (this is limited more by schedule size, not ROB size), so you do need the instructions to be interleaved in the code.  Hyperthreading will also help with this, but not with `div`, since both threads will compete for the single divider.

Answer (score -1):

Having no inline assembly kind of sucks.
Anyway, the function call overhead is actually extremely small. Parameters are passed in volatile registers and no cleanup is needed.

I don't have an assembler, and x64 targets don't support __asm, so I had no choice but to "assemble" my function from opcodes myself.

Obviously it depends on . I'm using mpir (gmp) as a reference to show the function produces correct results.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

// mulmod64(a, b, m) == (a * b) % m
typedef uint64_t(__cdecl *mulmod64_fnptr_t)(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t m);

uint8_t mulmod64_opcodes[] = {
    0x48, 0x89, 0xC8, // mov rax, rcx
    0x48, 0xF7, 0xE2, // mul rdx
    0x4C, 0x89, 0xC1, // mov rcx, r8
    0x48, 0xF7, 0xF1, // div rcx
    0x48, 0x89, 0xD0, // mov rax,rdx
    0xC3              // ret
};

mulmod64_fnptr_t mulmod64_fnptr;

void init() {
    DWORD dwOldProtect;
    VirtualProtect(
        &mulmod64_opcodes,
        sizeof(mulmod64_opcodes),
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,
        &dwOldProtect);
    // NOTE: reinterpret byte array as a function pointer
    mulmod64_fnptr = (mulmod64_fnptr_t)(void*)mulmod64_opcodes;
}

int main() {
    init();

    uint64_t a64 = 2139018971924123ull;
    uint64_t b64 = 1239485798578921ull;
    uint64_t m64 = 8975489368910167ull;

    // reference code
    mpz_t a, b, c, m, r;
    mpz_inits(a, b, c, m, r, NULL);
    mpz_set_ui(a, a64);
    mpz_set_ui(b, b64);
    mpz_set_ui(m, m64);
    mpz_mul(c, a, b);
    mpz_mod(r, c, m);

    gmp_printf("(%Zd * %Zd) mod %Zd = %Zd\n", a, b, m, r);

    // using mulmod64
    uint64_t r64 = mulmod64_fnptr(a64, b64, m64);
    printf("(%llu * %llu) mod %llu = %llu\n", a64, b64, m64, r64);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's ridiculous; just write the function in a `.asm` source file that you assemble and link normally.  Then you don't have to call it through a non-const function pointer (which increases the overhead), or change memory protection at run-time.

Comment: You could actually make your function pointer `const` and initialize it statically with a cast.  The linker should be able to handle that relocation.  However, I don't see a way around doing a `VirtualProtect` call at run-time.  This is unavoidable if you're going to include machine-code in an array.  (which should be `const`...)  **There's just no benefit to this approach, because it's easy to link asm sources with C sources.**